# Asp.net Masterpage not working

Tags: asp.net

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Home.css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            <div id="banner" style="font-family: Calibri, Serif; color: #FFFFFF">
               blah blah
            </div>
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Home.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Home.aspx.cs" Inherits="Home" 
MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" Title="Welcome to StuartStudios!"%>


<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
```

Does Home.aspx not print whatever I define in the ContentPlaceHolder1 ? At the minute it prints nothing out. :S

Answer (score 2):

When you specify markup in a ContentPlaceHolder inside of a MasterPage, that markup will only be rendered if the pages that use your master pages don't use the ContentPlaceHolder.  So in Home.aspx, if you get rid of the Contact1 element, you should see your "banner" div.

So if you want your banner div to appear on ALL pages, you should move it to outside the ContentPlaceHolder control.

On your individual pages that use your master page, the Content tag should contain the stuff that's unique to the specific page.

Answer (score 1):

No... ContentPlaceholder1 should be left blank in the masterpage.

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert in ASP.Net, but as far as I understand the way `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder />` works, when you add a `<asp:Content>` tag in your page file, you override the content of the `ContentPlaceHolder` in the master page.  The contents of which will only be displayed if you do not have a corresponding `Content` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Two things I see:

1. Your div in your master page has color set to white. So unless I'm mistaken, you're printing white on white.
2. Your Content item in Home.aspx IS empty, so why would it print anything else?

Comment: Oh, I think I see your confusion. In your masterpage where you have content inside of the contentplaceholder, that will be printed to the screen IF the page you go to does NOT define content for that contentplaceholder. For example, you could have 4 placeholders (header, menu, body, and footer). However, in most of your pages, you'd only want to provide the content for the body one. However, there may be rare exceptions where you want a special menu or special footer, then you can also provide that content. If you don't provide that content, then what's defined in the master page is shown.